# java Vowel Counter Using Switch Method

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am supposed to write a simple java application that counts each vowel in a string entered by the user and outputs the number of time each vowel occurs.

I don't understand why my code is checking each individual word in my string. I am getting the right amount of vowels for each word. Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VowelAnalyst
     {
//
//

public static void main (String[] args)
{
String userString;
int aCount = 0, eCount = 0, iCount = 0, oCount = 0, uCount = 0;
char vowels;

Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println ("enter string:");
userString = scan.nextLine();

for (int count = 0; count < userString.length(); count++)
{

vowels = userString.charAt(count);

    switch (vowels)
    {
    case 'a':
        aCount++;
        break;

    case 'e':
        eCount++;
        break;

    case 'i':
        iCount++;
        break;

    case 'o':
        oCount++;
        break;

    case 'u':
        uCount++;
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println ("Please enter valid string.");

    }

            System.out.println ("a: " +aCount);
            System.out.println ("e: " +eCount);
            System.out.println ("i: " +iCount);
            System.out.println ("o: " +oCount);
            System.out.println ("u: " +uCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: Technically, `y` could be considered a vowel too.

Comment: @mast3rch1ef... The recipe looks good to me :-P;-)

Comment: @assylias please enlighten us with y being a vowel ? :-)

Comment: what exactly is the problem.?

Comment: @MukulGoel [link](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/is-the-letter-y-a-vowel-or-a-consonant) => *"Whether the letter Y is a vowel or a consonant is therefore rather an arbitrary decision. The letter is probably more often used as a vowel, but in this role it's often interchangeable with the letter I. However, the consonant sound is not consistently represented in English spelling by any other letter, and perhaps for this reason Y tends traditionally to be counted among the consonants."*

Comment: @MukulGoel Interestingly, in French (my native language) [y is a vowel](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle). In English it seems to be border line, but more on the consonants side ;-)

Comment: @assylias, thats interesting. Thanks for the info :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you should move your below print statements out of your for loop, else they will print count after every character compared: -

```
System.out.println ("a: " +aCount);
System.out.println ("e: " +eCount);
System.out.println ("i: " +iCount);
System.out.println ("o: " +oCount);
System.out.println ("u: " +uCount);
```

**UPDATE**: -

Although the way you are doing is not a bad way, but you would be better if you maintain a `Map<Character, Integer>` to store the count of each `Vowel`. You need to initialize your Map with an initial count of 0 for each character, and then on each character read, just increment the count, if match is found in Map.

Here's a sample snippet: -

```
// This is `double-braces` initialization. 
// You can rather initialize your Map in a way you are comfortable with
Map<Character, Integer> vowels = new HashMap<Character, Integer>() {
    {
        put('a', 0);
        put('e', 0);
        put('i', 0);
        put('o', 0);
        put('u', 0);
    }
}; // Note the semi-colon here
```

And then your code of reading each character from string in for loop: -

```
for (int count = 0; count < userString.length(); count++)
{
    char ch = userString.charAt(count);
    ch = Character.toLowerCase(ch);

    if (vowels.containsKey(ch)) {
        vowels.put(ch, vowels.get(ch) + 1); 
    }
}

System.out.println(vowels);  // Will print each vowels with respective count
```

Comment: Hey thanks guys, new to this site, that was some awesome responding time.  And it solved my problem.  One more question.  Can my default be null in the switch statement? like so

Comment: @Mast3rCh1ef you don't need default. you can remove that line.

Comment: thanks again!  but what happens if an unknown character or special character is entered?

Comment: @Mast3rCh1ef. Then it will be ignored simply. You don't want to count them right? So, don't bother about them. Just ignore.

Comment: Perfect. Just curious, is there a way to count the left over letters in the string that aren't vowels with another case in the switch statement?

Comment: @Mast3rCh1ef. In that case, now you would need a default. And increment your consonants count in there. Provided there are only `vowels` and `consonants` in your string.

Comment: Accepted your answer.  Thanks again!  That makes sense, added the consonant count in my default case as well.

Comment: In your opinion is this the simplest way to go about this problem?  It seems like there has to be a short cut. But, I may not be that advanced with java yet.

Comment: @Mast3rCh1ef. Well, it is not a bad way. But using a HashMap would simplify you task so much. Just increment the count of the character in hashmap. Thats it.

Comment: @Mast3rCh1ef. I'll post a small snippet for that.

Comment: @Mast3rCh1ef. Now take a look at the new for-loop. How it is simplified to just 3 lines. With just a Map declaration initially.

Answer (score 0):

Do you guys really have to create a map to store some characters?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char[] vowels = "aeiouAEIOU".toCharArray();
    String text = "I am a Java programmer";
    int[] vowelsCount = new int[vowels.length];

    for (char textChar: text.toCharArray())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++)
        {
            char vowel = vowels[i];

            if (vowel == textChar)
            {
                vowelsCount[i]++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < vowelsCount.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(vowels[i] + " - " + vowelsCount[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a - 5
e - 1
i - 0
o - 1
u - 0
A - 0
E - 0
I - 1
O - 0
U - 0
```

Comment: I guess we don't have to do anything... both are good solutions.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: If you were going to do it that way, you'd be better off using `"eEaAoOIiuU"`, if your source language is English