# count vowels in a string in java

Tags: java

I want to count the vowels in each word in a string and print the number of vowels for each word. I just know how to count all the vowels in a string and I tried that. But I want the count of vowels for each word. How can I print that?

```
String s="hai hello";
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i)=='a'||s.charAt(i)=='e'||s.charAt(i)=='i'||s.charAt(i)=='o'||s.charAt(i)=='u')
            count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

If the **input** is "hai hello" then the **Expected output** will be "1 2".

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018361/java-vowel-counter-using-switch-method) might help you

Comment: What's the problem with the given code?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: output '1 2' ..that is right ?......word 1 has 2 vowel(a,i) and word 2 has 2 vowel (e,o)

Comment: First, find a way to split your `String` in `String[] words`.  Then, all you have to do is to define a `char[] vowels` to be able to simplify your tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex for that...

```
String string = "hai hello";
String[] wordAr = string.split(" ");
for (String s : wordAr) {
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?i)[^aeiouy]", "").length());
}
```

(?i) will make the character case-insensitive

Answer (score 1):

i try to solve your problem

```
        String string = "hai hello";
        String[] wordAr = string.split(" ");
        int count = 0;
        for (String s : wordAr) {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == 'a' || s.charAt(i) == 'e' || s.charAt(i) == 'i' || s.charAt(i) == 'o' || s.charAt(i) == 'u') {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.print(count + "\t");
            count = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
String result = Arrays.asList(string.split(" ")).stream().map(s -> countVowel(s))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

where countVowel returns the nr of vowels in a string (see "pantha istiaque" answer) to get the whole result

Answer (score 0):

You can use condition in your loops :

```
if (s.charAt(i) == ' ' ) {
  system.out.println(count)
  count = 0;
}
```

it will print and set count a zero each time you see a blanck.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Map<String, Integer> countVowelsByWords(String str) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    Arrays.stream(str.toLowerCase().split("[^a-z]+"))
          .distinct()
          .forEach(word -> {
              int count = 0;

              for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                  char ch = word.charAt(i);

                  if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
                      count++;
              }

              map.put(word, count);
          });

    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Sam {
public static void main(String... args) {
    String str="hai hello";
    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
    String[] s=str.split(" ");
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
         list.add(a(s[i])); 
    }
    System.out.println(list); //output : [2,2]      
}

static int a(String s) {
    int cou=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i)=='a'||s.charAt(i)=='e'||s.charAt(i)=='i'||s.charAt(i)=='o'||s.charAt(i)=='u') {
            cou++;
        }
    }
    return cou;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show another simple concept...Use the [String#replaceAll()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall) method with a [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx) to count the number of vowels within a word or string.

The regex (`"(?i)[^aeiou]"`) used within the [String#replaceAll()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall) method basically tells the method to replace all characters with a Null String (**""**) that is not **a**, **e**, **i**, **o**, or **u** *regardless* of letter case. We then take the remaining number of characters (which would be all vowels) as the count for the number of vowels within the word or string since they were the only characters that were **not** replaced:

```
String a = "This sentence has vowels";
int vowelCount = 0;
String[] words = a.split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    vowelCount = words[i].replaceAll("(?i)[^aeiou]", "").length();
    System.out.println("Word #" + (i + 1) + " [" + words[i] + 
                       "] contains " + vowelCount + " vowels.");
}
```

Console output wold look like:

```
Word #1 [This] contains 1 vowels.
Word #2 [sentence] contains 3 vowels.
Word #3 [has] contains 1 vowels.
Word #4 [vowels] contains 2 vowels.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count vowels using java 8 :

```
  String str="a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog";
  List<Character> vowels=Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
  Long vowelCount = str.chars().filter(c -> vowels.contains((char) c)).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="hello";
long count = str.chars().filter((x) -> {
        return (x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u');
}).count();
System.out.println("count:::: "+count);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.